# Session ID embedded in URL's is very annonying

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET 4 site with url's having session string embedded in them. Due to this Google index the same page multiple times, all with different session id's. This is affecting my ranking. Earlier i also had the aspautodetectcookie string appended to the url. But i was able to remove it, however the session id embedded in the url remains a problem still.

If my url is http://www.somesite.com/ViewProduct.aspx?ID=12, it shows up like this http://www.somesite.com/S(yya4h4rf4gjh5eo4uazix2t055)X(1))/ViewProduct.aspx?ID=12. I want it to show like http://www.somesite.com/ViewProduct.aspx?ID=12 all the time.

Here are some settings in my web.config that may help you help me

```
<authentication mode="Forms">             
<forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/AccessDenied.aspx" name="FORMAUTH" />
</authentication>  

<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="15" /> 

<anonymousIdentification cookieless="AutoDetect" enabled="false" />
```

Now one user asked to change cookieless="true" to fix the problem. However in the artcle http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Cookieless-Session-State.aspx the guy says that by adding cookieless = "true" session id 'will be' embedded in all page URLs.

Can anyone tell me how remove this session from the url - forever.

I am running on IIS 7 but do not have much access to the admin features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `cookieless="false"` that will solve the problem you are seeing with Google.

However this means that any browser, which doesn't support cookies, will get a new session per request.  If you want more help, please tell us how you are using the sessions.

Comment: thanks nick, but as you see in the web.config, cookieless is set to false. ASP.NET still generates the session in url's. My worst problem is when google bot indexes the page, it does that with a new url, since a new session gets embedded every time

Comment: By the way, you meant cookieless=false in the sessionstate attribute right?

Comment: Try it in both, because the GoogleBot is always going to be anonymous.

Comment: do you anticipate it may break the application in any way if done and how do I test that it's fixed? I mean why did this guy take out so much time to write this http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Cookieless-Session-State.aspx if it could be done with just a setting. Sorry just thinking aloud

Comment: anonymousIdentification does not have cookieless=false option. By both, what did you mean?

Comment: @Matt - I can't explain why he took so much time to explain it. But the only reason cookieless exists is if you want to have a session state that is available across requests without relying on cookies. You never explained how you were using the sessions, so it is hard to say what an anonymous user like GoogleBot might gain from having their session tracked across requests using the cookieless method.

Comment: I guess sessions were to be used in the shopping cart, but since that's not in use now, I am not so sure it's  being used elsewhere. You mentioned 'try it in both. sessionstate cookieless is already set to false. whereelse to set it and after that how do i test is sessions are not appending to the url?